# what kind of data for jqGrid select

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

i wanna use select in jqGrid when i try to edit row.

i set colModel like this:

```
{name:'scenic',index:'scenic',width:90, editable:true,editoptions:{size:"20",maxlength:"30"}, sortable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{dataUrl:"/admins/type"}
```

and my url return data like this:

```
[{"key":1,"value":"123"},{"key":2,"value":"456"},{"key":3,"value":"789"},{"key":4,"value":"00"}]
```

but the problem is, i got error in browser when i renturn data like that, so what kind of data should i return and also i can get the row value when i opening edit window.
the error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"key":1,"value":"123"},{"key":2,"value":"456"},{"key":3,"value":"789"},{"key":4,"value":"00"}]
```

any help will be appreciate.........:)

Comment: always important to provide as much detail about an error as possible... `got error` isn't very informative

Comment: thanks for reminding me.....i just edit it for adding error message....

Comment: I Updated my answer, Please see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid expect that `dataUrl` return HTML fragment with `<select><option>...</option>...</select>`. If the `dataUrl` returns JSON data then one should use `buildSelect` to convert JSON data to the HTML fragment which jqGrid require.

The next error in your code: you specify `editoptions` property **twice** which is an syntax error. 
The code could be something like

```
{name: "scenic", width: 90, sortable: true,
    editable: true, edittype: "select"
    editoptions: {
        size: "20",
        maxlength: "30",
        dataUrl: "/admins/type",
        buildSelect: function (data) {
             var s = "<select>", i, l, item;
             if (data != null && data.length) {
                 for (i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
                     item = data[i];
                     s += '<option value="' + item.key + '">' +
                             item.value + '</option>';
                 }
             }
             return s + "</select>";
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally you should use `ajaxSelectOptions` option to inform `jQuery.ajax` about the format of expected data:

```
ajaxSelectOptions: { dataType: "json" }
```

If you don't do this it could be that `data` in `buildSelect` will be needed to convert of object using `data = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);`.

Comment: @MadisonRong: You are welcome! If the select looks "strange" you should verify CSS which you included on the page and to post the picture which shows the problem.

Comment: @MadisonRong: You should just post new question where you clear describe what you need exactly. Do you need set the same background image in all cells on the column or you need to set individual background image in every cell? Where is the input for the URL or the CSS class which need be set on the `<td>` element? And so on. I suppose that you need either specify `classes` property for the column or use `cellattr` callback or to use custom formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Your data format is correct. You need to add `formatter` to your colModel. Something like this:

```
{name:'scenic',index:'scenic',width:90, editable:true,editoptions:{size:"20",maxlength:"30"}, formatter: "select"}
```

Try and I hope that help you.